# How to figure out series has pattern?

Tags: math, statistics

I want to create a function to detect whether a series of numbers has a pattern or not.

`f(list) -> boolean`

For example this function has a pattern and it's not random (function must return true) :

[image: Series with pattern]

But this one is random (function must return false) :

[image: Series without pattern]

I want to know is there any statistical functions to handle this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by pattern? Do you mean that the first function is roughly a cosine curve while the second is not? And what language do you want to use?

Comment: I want to use this function to extracting features for training ANN. I want to check data is randomly generated or not. I'm using python.

Comment: There is no 100% reliable way to figure out if a given data set is randomly generated unless you have more info about what all "non-random" data looks like. For example, if you know that your non-random data is more or less a cosine curve, you can check for that, but you will still have false positives by pure chance. Imagine you are tossing fair coins and are looking at the results, and by pure chance have heads 8 time in a row. Does that mean that the data was not randomly generated? Of course not, merely that the data set it produced is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Quick and easy: throw your data into the most advanced compression algorithm you can find.  If it achieves high compression rate the data has a pattern, if not, it doesn't.  Your choice of what qualifies as a high compression rate is just that, your choice.